# select statements in if conditions (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

I wish to execute a select statement based on the value of a variable.
I have tried the following

```
SET @thismonth = MONTH(NOW());
SET @thisday = DAY(NOW()) ;
SET @thisperiod = IF(@thisday > 15 , 'late' , 'early') ;
IF @thisperiod ='late' THEN   

        SELECT 
                t1.produce ,
                t1.state
            FROM
                seasonal_food_guide AS t1
            WHERE
                (
                    t1.month_number = @thismonth+1
                    AND t1.period <> @thisperiod
                    AND t1.avaliable = 'no'
                ) OR (
                    
                    t1.month_number = @thismonth+1
                    AND t1.period = @thisperiod
                    AND t1.avaliable = 'no'
                ) 
;
ELSE SELECT
                t1.produce ,
                t1.state
            FROM
                seasonal_food_guide AS t1
            WHERE
                (
                    t1.month_number = @thismonth
                    AND t1.period <> @thisperiod
                    AND t1.avaliable = 'no'
                )
OR 
(
                    
                    t1.month_number = @thismonth+1
                    AND t1.period = @thisperiod
                    AND t1.avaliable = 'no'
                );
END IF;
```

I can't seem to see what I am doing wrong. If IF can't be used, how would I go about achieving the same thing?

thank you

Comment: Is this code in a stored procedure? Control statements like `IF` are only allowed in procedures, not ordinary queries.

Comment: I tried it in a stored procedure as well, it did not make a difference. Have you tried  it? did it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your queries using CASE WHEN to perform this. Make a cross join to a query that prepares your "variables" then you can simplistically replace it with case when:

```
        SELECT 
            t1.produce ,
            t1.state
        FROM
            seasonal_food_guide AS t1
            CROSS JOIN
            (SELECT 
              MONTH(NOW()) AS thismonth,
              DAY(NOW()) = thisday
              CASE WHEN DAY(NOW()) > 15 THEN 'late' ELSE 'early' END as thisperiod) x
        WHERE
          CASE WHEN thisperiod = 'late' THEN --equivalent of your top IF
            CASE WHEN
            (
                t1.month_number = thismonth+1
                AND t1.period <> thisperiod
                AND t1.avaliable = 'no'
            ) OR (            
                t1.month_number = thismonth+1
                AND t1.period = thisperiod
                AND t1.avaliable = 'no'
            )  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
         ELSE -- equivalent of your ELSE
           CASE WHEN
            (
                t1.month_number = thismonth
                AND t1.period <> thisperiod
                AND t1.avaliable = 'no'
            )
            OR 
            (    
                t1.month_number = thismonth+1
                AND t1.period = thisperiod
                AND t1.avaliable = 'no'
            ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
          END = 1
```

I think you might have an error in your query btw, the OR seems redundant on t1.period in the first query.

Comment: the OR in my statement is not redundant.

Comment: Look at your first query, you have `(monthnum = x and period = y and avail = z) or (monthnum = x and period <> y and avail = z)` - this is the same as not having an OR at all and saying `(monthnum = x period is not null and avail = z)` hence my note that the or on t1.period is redundant; you say "period is y or period is not y" - the only thing that saying "blah = y or blah <> y" does is make sure blah isn't null

Comment: The second query is slightly different; it's like you made a copy paste error on the first query; check it?

Comment: At your insistence that is was correct, I modified the answer btw, hopefully easier to see how the logic of using case when aligns with your logic of IF, but this could certainly be optimized to be easier to read and work with; avail is always NO so that could just be a predicate ANDed with an expression regarding the months etc

Comment: The dates thing seems to be a complex way of saying "between the 15th of last/this month and the 15th of this/next month". It might be easier to do a bit of date math to realign the "current month" to flick over on the 15th of every month. Something like "get the month of (now minus 15 days plus 1 month)" - on the 1-15 of jan that formula returns "jan" and on the 16-31 of jan it returns "feb".. but this is a guess at what you're trying to do because it's not always possible to work out the problem someone is trying to solve from a broken solution they posted

Comment: thank you for your solution. It works. In my query, the OR was not redundant but in yours it would have been. the first solution you gave me was what worked. Would it be okay to update it back to what it was to help others?

Comment: in the second section (else) t1.month_number = @thismonth and not t1.month_number = @thismonth+1

Comment: Not sure what you mean but I haven't changed anything about your logic, I just swapped IF for CASE and @variables for columnnames-in-a-subquery. I pointed out that your logic looks wrong because it seems inconsistent/has redundancies. In your first query, both mentions of monthnum have a +1 but in your second query only one of them does. I don't know for sure if this is an error, you say it isn't; that's fine - it's just if it's not an error then there is no point in having the OR in the first query,for reasons mentioned: `(a=1 and b=2 and c=3) or (a=1 and b!=2 and c=3)` same as `a=1 and c=3`

Comment: okay, No problem. thank you for your answer, that was a BIG help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will be able use IF-THEN-ELSE or CASE statements in stored procedures not in one-time execution SQL queries.
https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-procedure-tutorial.aspx